# Quill Delta to HTML & Submit Validation [php & Smarty]

Tags: php, jquery, html, quill

I have 2 problems with implementation Quill to my site.

1. I want convert Delta to HTML. For that i use this:

   ```
   var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
   modules: {
   toolbar: true
   },
   theme: 'snow'
   });

   var form = document.querySelector('form');
   form.onsubmit = function() {
   var text = document.querySelector('input[name=text]');
   text.value = JSON.stringify(quill.root.innerHTML);
   };
   ```

   And HTMl Form:

   ```
              <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text" class="control-label">{$lang.a_text}:</label>
            <input name="text" type="hidden">
            <div id="editor-container">{$row.text|esc}</div>
             </div>
          <input type="submit" name="ok" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
   ```

In this case Print `"` on top and bottom in text and print already to output. Where is the problem with that?

My 2-nt problem is form validation.
I have this to my php script:

```
        if ($_POST['ok']) {

        if (mb_strlen(Core::Input($_POST['text'])) < 2 || mb_strlen(Core::Input($_POST['text'])) > 50000)
            $error = 'invalid text length!';
    }
```

But when i click Save on `<input type="submit" name="ok" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">` the error no show, and form is successful empty save to db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first issue change this:

```
text.value = JSON.stringify(quill.root.innerHTML);
```

to This:

```
text.value = quill.root.innerHTML;
```

And will be work correct

Comment: Thanks, that work correct!
Do you have idea how to fix my 2-nt problem?

Answer (score 0):

the second problem, how about this

```
if ($_POST['ok']) {
    if (mb_strlen(Core::Input($_POST['text'])) > 2 && mb_strlen(Core::Input($_POST['text'])) < 50000) {
        // do save data

    } else {
        $error = 'invalid text length!';
        // do displaying error
    }
}
```